# Magento Changing Product URL for store Views

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

We have various domains but the two I will focus on are www.scalesmart.com and www.scalesmart.nl

They are two websites running on the same install. The NL site is for our Netherlands office.

What we are struggling on is changing the URL for the products to be in the native language.

For example in the database we have set the two url keys as:

```
http://www.scalesmart.nl/radwag-mac-vochtbepalingsbalansen

http://www.scalesmart.com/radwag-mac-moisture-balance
```

Unfortunately the NL store does not pick up this change in the store view and defaults to the English Language version. If i manually enter the NL URL into a browser i get a 404 (set to redirect to homepage)

I have set the URL Key attribute to Store View but to no avail.

Comment: Which version you are using ? And do you want to change URL for each store view ?

Comment: We are using version 1.7.0.2

As we work through the product database making translations we aim to have an URL in the language of the store view. As it stands the default URL overides the store view.

Comment: Magento won't store different URL rewrites for other store views.if you have set two different URL's for two stores, you need to check if they are really called

Comment: I think i understand, i changed the attribute to Storeview for the URLkey, what I think you are saying is that just by changing that it wont automatically start using the new URLS.

Comment: What it sounds like you need is to just "Add store codes to URL" - which will leave your URL keys alone, but prefix all respective URLs with your store code. This should then allow your store switcher to function

Comment: The stores run fine, all i want to do is have different URLkeys for the same product.